# Exercise 6.6.A in Foundations of Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

The exercise is "Suppose $X$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-scheme. Verify that there is a natural bijection between maps $X → \mathbb{A}_C^1$ in the category of $\mathbb{C}$-schemes and functions on $X$."

Butt directly above it in FOAG ([http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf)), it states "If $X$ is a scheme, there is a bijection between the maps $X → \mathbb{A}^1$ and global sections of the structure sheaf."

Here is the confusion: what do we have to show? Isn't it immediate? I feel as if there is a subtley missing, but what?

Comment: You are being asked to verify the claim! The explanation given above does not constitute a proof (mostly because it does not address the naturality at all).

Comment: Is the naturality here referring to that given in 6.6.2?

Comment: Yes, and it's also mentioned in 6.6.1 when he says "the bijection is functorial in X".